# How do I set a .txt file as publicly accessible on CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, webserver

I have CodeIgniter running on an Apache server on AWS. For verification, I need to place a text file in my website's root directory. It should be:

mywebsite.com/verification.txt

I've tried adding a view and controller, but as everything expects PHP files, this predicatively failed me, resulting in a 404 error. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [upload a file with codeigniter](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html)

Comment: This shows how to create an upload form, but not how to display a txt file on the server. Did I miss something when I read through it?

Comment: Looks like I misread your Q: "*For verification, I need to upload a text file to my website's root directory*". Can you please clarify, editing your post?

Comment: I've updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried to upload the verification.txt file to your www root folder where is placed the main index.php file ? This should work as simply as a robots.txt file works.

Comment: Wow, I way overthought the whole thing. This worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can give the file permission, In case anyone from the outside world gets access to your system they can do anything with these files. Including deleting them.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 verification.txt
```

Comment: When I say "publicly accessible" I mean accessible over the internet by the general public. Sorry if I was confusing, but I don't think this solves my problem.